# postgresql if statement condition is ignored

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to execute this command.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF 'schemax' = '' THEN
   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schemax TO ;
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schemax TO ;
END IF;
END;
$$;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 4:  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO ;

The if statement is not equal 'schemax' != '', then why it enters the if statement?
I expect it to be ignored and end the code.
Thanks!

Comment: you are compating only two strings, which are not equal so the condition is never true

Comment: "*Why it enters the if statement?*" - it doesn't enter the block to *run* the statements. But it's still *parsing* all your code, and you have a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Found a fix

```sql
    DO
    $$
    BEGIN
    IF 'schemax' = '' THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schemax TO ';
        EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schemax TO ';
    END IF;
    END;
    $$;
```

Comment: you still have a syntax error in the GRANT-command, but now the parser doesn't discover it, and your branch never executes. So I am not sure what this code is supposed to do.